# Using os.path.join with os.path.getsize, returning FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.4

In conjunction with my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041837/how-to-open-multiple-files-one-by-one-and-print-the-contents-in-python), I'm onto printing the filenames with their sizes next to them in a sort of list. Basically I am reading filenames from one file (which are added by the user), taking the filename and putting it in the path of the working directory to print it's size one-by-one, however I'm having an issue with the following block:

```
print("\n--- Stats ---\n")

with open('userdata/addedfiles', 'r') as read_files:
        file_lines = read_files.readlines()

        # get path for each file and find in trackedfiles
        # use path to get size

        print(len(file_lines), "files\n")

        for file_name in file_lines:
        # the actual files should be in the same working directory
            cwd = os.getcwd() 

            fpath = os.path.join(cwd, file_name)
            fsize = os.path.getsize(fpath)

            print(file_name.strip(), "-- size:", fsize)
```

which is returning this error:

```
tolbiac wpm-public → ./main.py --filestatus

--- Stats ---

1 files

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 332, in <module>
    main()
  File "./main.py", line 323, in main
    parseargs()
  File "./main.py", line 317, in parseargs
    tracking()
  File "./main.py", line 204, in tracking
    fsize = os.path.getsize(fpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tolbiac/code/wpm-public/file.txt\n'
tolbiac wpm-public →
```

So it looks like something is adding a \n to the end of file_name, I'm not sure if thats something used in the getsize module, I tried this with os.stat, but it did the same thing.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reading in a file, you need to be aware of how the data is being seperated. In this case, the read-in file has a filename once per line seperated out by that `\n` operator. Need to strip it then before you use it.

```
for file_name in file_lines:
    file_name = file_name.strip()
    # rest of for loop
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I should have thought to use this before.